i want to know how to affect Map Reduce on hive files stored as avrofile
i have a mysql db stored i imported it to datawarehouse using
sqoop import-all-tables \--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/election_tunisie_2024 --username root --password cloudera --as-avrodatafile --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/election_with_metadata.db --fields-terminated-by ',' --num-mappers 1

and now i want to perform map reducer on them but when i do
hdfs dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/electionsMeta/votes/part-m-00000.avro 


no data is showing only schema of the avrofile with other weird letters
i tried
avro-tools-1.11.1.jar totext file.avro > file.txt and it didn t work
